# Toggle between One and Two Elements Horizontally with slide animation - AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs, animation

I want two states. The first with element 1 centered by itself. When a ng-click is activated another element (element 2) slides in from the right (animated) pushing element one too the side so both elements are centered on the page (second state). Then if the ng-click is toggled again the reverse happens and element 2 slides out of the view to the right and element 1 is centered back to the original first state, and ideas on how I could acheive this with angularJS? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added sample of how this might look. The concept is simple; first you use angular's `ng-class`directive to add and remove css classes based on a property on the controller. This property is toggled through `ng-click` on the first element. Then you add css3 transitions to the elements that wrap your content. So when the width of the first element goes from `100% -> 50%`, the width of the second element goes from `0% -> 50%`. Since they share the same transition class, the second element expands at the same rate the first element shrinks.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.showFull = true
}
```

```css
.content{
  text-align: center;
  transition: width linear 1s;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}
.content span{
  font-size:10em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.fullWidth{
  width:100%;
}
.halfWidth{
  width:50%;
}
.noWidth{
  width:0;
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="content red" ng-class="showFull ? 'fullWidth' : 'halfWidth'" ng-click="showFull = !showFull">
      <span>1</span>
  </div><div class="content blue" ng-class="showFull ? 'noWidth' : 'halfWidth'">
      <span>2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight improvement over previous answer if someone need to slide using a button.
This implementation is very simple for sliding between two divs.
Thanks to @Sasang

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function MainCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.showFull = true
}
```

```css
.content{
  text-align: center;
  transition: width linear 0.2s;
  overflow:hidden;
  display:inline-block;
}
.content span{
  font-size:10em;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.fullWidth{
  width:100%;
}
.halfWidth{
  width:50%;
}
.noWidth{
  width:0;
}
.red{
    background-color: red;
}
.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="content red" ng-class="showFull ? 'fullWidth' : 'noWidth'" >
      <span><button ng-click="showFull = !showFull">Next</button></span>
  </div><div class="content blue" ng-class="showFull ? 'noWidth' : 'fullWidth'">
      <span><button ng-click="showFull = !showFull">Prev</button></span>
  </div>
</div>
```